# What is the Vec3b type?

Tags: opencv, types

I came across the type `Vec3b` in `OpenCV`. I just couldn't find a description if this type and why we use it.

Do you know of any reference that describes such type, or, if you can clarify it this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Vec3b is the abbreviation for "vector with 3 byte entries"

Here those byte entries are unsigned char values to represent values between 0 .. 255.

Each byte typically represents the intensity of a single color channel, so on default, Vec3b is a single RGB (or better BGR) pixel. So Vec3bVar[0] might be the blue color part, [1] green and [2] red.

But it could be any other 24 bit 3 channel pixel value like HSV.

Answer (score 7):

`vec3b` is defined as 3 uchars vec: From [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec):

```
typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b;
```